# How to get city information in android by longitude and latitude

Tags: java, android, location, geocoding, city

I am making android app now. I got some problem about getting locations.

In my code, I made my app get longitude and latitude by GPS. However, I have continued to fail to get city name by longitude and latitude. I don't know why my code goes to Exception even though there are no wrong things in my code.

Here is my code for getting city name

```
    ackage org.androidtown.getcurrentlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GetCurrentLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private LocationListener locationListener = null;

    private Button btnGetLocation = null;
    private EditText editLocation = null;
    private ProgressBar pb = null;

    private static final String TAG = "Debug";
    private Boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_current_location);

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        editLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);

        btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = displayGpsStatus();
        if (flag) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onClick");

            editLocation.setText("Please!! move your device to see the changes in coordinates.\nWait..");

            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {return;}

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);

            }
        else{
            alertbox("GPS Status!!", "Your GPS is : OFF");
        }
    }

    private Boolean displayGpsStatus(){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
        boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(gpsStatus){
            return true;
        }
    else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disable").setCancelable(false).setTitle("**GPS Status**").setPositiveButton("Gps On", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
            editLocation.setText("");
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location changed : Lat " + loc.getLatitude() +"Lng: "+loc.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String longtitude = "Longtitude: "+loc.getLongitude();
            Log.v(TAG, longtitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: "+loc.getLatitude();
            Log.v(TAG, latitude);


            String cityName = "default";
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            // addresses
            try{
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if(addresses.size()>0) {
                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String s = longtitude + "\n" + latitude +
                    "\n\nMy Current City is : "+ cityName;
                    editLocation.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){

        }



    }
}
```

On the above code, this part is main code to get city name by longitude and latitude. There is no problem to get longitude and latitude. The only problem is to get city name.

```
String cityName = "default";
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            // addresses
            try{
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if(addresses.size()>0) {
                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String s = longtitude + "\n" + latitude +
                    "\n\nMy Current City is : "+ cityName;
                    editLocation.setText(s);
        }
```

Thank you for reading my question. Have a great day(?) midnight.

Comment: Can you please post the exception ?

Comment: Exception is generated by below code's addresses doesn't have any List<Address> . That means it is not initialized..

List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);

Comment: Use  [Google Search Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) for getting addresses.

Comment: Instead of geocoder(Which can give exceptions at time) use location APIs from google to get location address from lat lng

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try to use Google API!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First thing you shouldn't call getFromLocation from main thread as this method is synchronous and may take a long time to do its work, so you should not call it from the main, user interface (UI) thread of your app. you should use Intent service class.
Here is code for it:


public class GetAddressService extends IntentService {
    // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
    // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;
    //protected DataEntry.AddressResultReceiver mReceiver;
    private static final String TAG = "GetAddressService";

    public GetAddressService() {
        super("GetAddressService");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
        Log.e(TAG,"mReceiver"+mReceiver);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
                String errorMessage = "";
                // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
                Location mCurrentLocation = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                            mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    errorMessage = "Service error: ";
                    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, e);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                    // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
                    errorMessage = "invalid_lat_long_used";
                    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                            "Latitude = " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() +
                            ", Longitude = " +
                            mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
                }
                // Handle case where no address was found.
                if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                    if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                        errorMessage = "no_address_found";
                        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                    }
                    deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT,errorMessage);
                }else {
                    String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String countryName = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String rLocation = cityName + "," + countryName;
                    Log.e(TAG, "location: " + rLocation);
                    deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,rLocation);
                }
    }

//To deliver the result back to the activity which started the service

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
        //mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
        mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
        Log.e(TAG,"Delivering result"+message);
    }


}


//Constant class to store all constants in one place

public final class Constants {
    public static final int SUCCESS_RESULT = 0;
    public static final int FAILURE_RESULT = 1;
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
            "your package name";
    public static final String RECEIVER = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RECEIVER";
    public static final String RESULT_DATA_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME +
            ".RESULT_DATA_KEY";
    public static final String LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA = PACKAGE_NAME +
            ".LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA";

}


//call this GetAddressService from your activity

private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GetAddressService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER,mResultReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA,loc);
        startService(intent);
        }



//class to receive the address back from the service
 class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver{

        /**
         * Create a new ResultReceive to receive results.  Your
         * {@link #onReceiveResult} method will be called from the thread running
         * <var>handler</var> if given, or from an arbitrary thread if null.
         *
         * @param handler
         */
        public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);
            Log.e(TAG,"Address is:"+mAddressOutput);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think my parameter 'Location loc' is getting the Location value where it is called. I can figure out that the Location value is initialized because loc.getLongitude() and loc.getLatitude is working. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you are trying to tell here. wasn't your question about that you have lat/lng but you are not able to retrieve city name from that??